# Prove that a set is a subgroup of $S_G$ (the set of all permutations of a group G)

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, permutations

The question:

Suppose that $G$ is a group, and $\forall a\in G$, $f_a:G\to G$ is defined as $f_a(x)=ax, \forall x\in G$. If $S_G$ is the set of all permutations of G,  prove that $H=\left\{ f_a:a\in G\right\}$ is a subgroup of $S_G$.

How would I prove this? Is there a way to use the Two-Step method?

How do I show that an inverse and identity element exist?

Comment: Which part is giving you problems? It is a straightforward application of the definition.

Comment: I think I'm just confused as to how this happens when dealing with permutations or symmetric groups

Comment: So let's start with first part: You want to show that the identity map $G\to G$ is in the given set. So you need to find an element $g\in G$ such that $f_g$ is the identity. Which element satisfies this?

Comment: Should $g=1$ satisfy this? Since $f_1=x$?

Comment: $f_1$ is not equal to $x$ (but $f_1(x) = x$ indeed which is what you wanted).

Comment: So this shows that the identity element is in $H$?

Comment: Yes. You are also almost done showing that the subset is closed under composition (in the comments to the answer). So now you just need to show that it has inverses. What would your guess be as to what $g\in G$ gives the inverse to $f_h$?

Comment: Well if the identity is $x$, then $f^{-1}=\frac{1}{a}$, so $\frac{1}{a}$?

Comment: What is $a$? What do you mean by writing fractions?

Comment: I'm not sure - this is what was confusing me in the problem

Comment: But there were no fractions in the problem. And the problem defines $f_a$ for each $a\in G$, so I am not sure what the confusion is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show that the composition of $f_a$ and $f_b$ is again of the same form, so is in $H$ as well. This shouldn't be too hard. Then you know $H$ is closed under the operation of composition (in $S_G$).

The identity of $H$ is also of this form, namely it's $f_a$ for $a = ?$

And the inverse of $f_a \in H$ is also of this form, namely....

Then $H$ is indeed a subgroup, if you have shown all of these.

Comment: $(f_a \circ f_b)(x)=f_a ( f_b (x)) = f_a (ax) = a^2 x$?

Comment: @jaska not quite. Your $n$ becomes $b$ which then disappears? Be careful. Compute $(f_a \circ f_b)(x)$ indeed.

Comment: oops - i mistyped the subscript. is it correct now?

Comment: No, $f_b(x)$ does not equal $ax$, but ..

Comment: Oh - $(f_a \circ f_b)(x) = f_a(f_b(x))=f_a(bx)=(ab)x$

Comment: So as this holds for all $x$, $f_a \circ f_b = \ldots$